# How can each user on a machine install his/her own pseudodistributed hadoop cluster?

Tags: linux, hadoop, bigdata

So, let us say, there are different users which use a server, and each one of them want to experiment/play with Hadoop by installing their own Hadoop in pseudo-distributed mode. How can each of them have that done without causing conflicts between the ports of different users? Also, notice that none of them has admin rights.